# Comparing Espresso Stout to a Coffee Stout

Tags: beer, brewing, coffee

I'm curious to hear everyone's take on the differences that they perceive in an espresso stout vs a coffee stout. Is this something that you would classify as a widely different beer or very similar? If you find them to be vastly different how would you go about adding your coffee to the beer?

Answer (score 1):

Espresso is just a method of making coffee.  What if it was "Drip Filter Coffee Stout" ?!

When I have added coffee to a stout (and I've only done it once), I used pre-roated coffee beans, and coarsely crushed them in a mortar & pestle.  I put these into the secondary-phase of fermentation for 3 days.

But... in beer, coffee is a fairly simple flavour addition.  I think the big thing, is not too add *too much*, as it gets astringent quickly.